# How can overlap this image in stack?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm trying to overlap this two images using stack but I'm not getting the result right:

[image: this is the image]

here is my code

```
Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 100.0),
                  child: Stack(
                    clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 4.0),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          gradient: LinearGradient(
                            begin: Alignment.topRight,
                            end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                            colors: [
                              Constants.color1,
                              Constants.color2,
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        child: CircleAvatar(
                          radius: 60,
                          backgroundImage: ExactAssetImage('assets/1 (1).jpeg'),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Positioned(
                        right: 90,
                        child: CircleAvatar(
                          radius: 60,
                          backgroundImage: ExactAssetImage('assets/1 (2).jpeg'),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
```

I have try using rows and positioning still yet, I'm not getting it.

Comment: remove padding from container

Comment: i have still yet i am not getting it, the padding was not there before but when i keep trying so many thing that is when i add that to test but is not giving me that look of the image

Comment: I can see some space between the 2 images. I guess you want to remove that space. Right?

Comment: No i dont what to remove it, the image is what i want to achieve...

Comment: I am sorry @Gbenga, I am not being able to get you. Do you want to bring those 2 images closer so that there is no gap between them? Or you are looking for something else?

Comment: okay... let me explain, better.... my code brings those images together but i the image there is small gap in the male image... that is what i want to achieve.. i want there should be small gap....... i have use border but border accept only want color and i am use gradient color for app background, so if i color the border with one color is not matching with background color

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I played around a bit and made it!

Learnings I took for myself from the task:

1. Stack has the Size of its biggest child but BEFORE it gets positioned. So a circle with radius of 60 and right or left positioning of 120 would not be visible at all, because it was moved "out of the area" of the Stack (unless there is no bigger element in the stack which widens the Stack area or the circle has padding which widens it as well).
2. PathFillType.evenOdd means that where both surfaces/paths overlap the widget gets drawn.

So here my code:

```
   Stack(
    children: [
      Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            begin: Alignment.topRight,
            end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
            colors: [
              Colors.yellow,
              Colors.blue,
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Positioned(
        left: 80,
        child: ClipPath(
          clipper: MyCustomClipper(offset: 16), **// left - radius - offset = gap -> so 80 - 60 - 16 = 4**
          child: CircleAvatar(
            radius: 60,
            backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/images/profile.png'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      CircleAvatar(
        radius: 60,
        backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/images/profile.png'),
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

With MyCustomClipper class as such:

```
class MyCustomClipper extends CustomClipper<Path>{

  MyCustomClipper({this.offset});
  final double offset;

  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    var path = Path();
    final radius = size.width/2;
    path.addOval(Rect.fromCircle(center: Offset(0 - offset,radius), radius: radius));
    path.addOval(Rect.fromCircle(center: Offset(radius,radius), radius: radius + 1));
    path.fillType = PathFillType.evenOdd;
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(covariant CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: the space in between is too much..... how can i reduce the space?

Comment: i have change the figure but, i no changes affected

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "I have edited the figure". I have edited the code so you can easily change the space between.

Comment: make sure you also change the MyCustomClipper class so it can take the gap parameter as input. For me by all respect, it works perfectly.

Comment: Ohh, I see. Look I changed the code again. There was one small mistake about the path and I was actually describing it wrong. Now I can move them around perfectly only by changing the new offset parameter. So whenever you change the left parameter of positioned, you have to change the offset parameter as well so it satisfies the equation I commented! Tell me does it work now?